Is this allowed within the workplace
Is a manager allowed to move an employees desk from the shared open plan office space with all the other employees to be in a 3x3m office with them?
Not a single other person shares an office with their manager. The employee has been there for 17 months.
The former desk isn’t needed by anyone else and all performance appraisals of the employee have been above satisfactory.
Is this allowed in regards to Australian Fair Work?
No explanation has been given towards the move. The manager unfortunately has always micromanaged the employee, making them keep a minute by minute log of what the employee does everyday etc.

Please note that in contrast to "The Workplace", answers here can come from different juristictions other than the one you asked about. They are clearly tagged. You are encouraged to treat them with curiosity, but you are free to reserve your "accept" mark for the one that actually helps you for your juristiction.

I did my best to edit this into shape, I am not sure why it got 4 downvotes. Maybe someone can leave some constructive criticism what to improve?

@nvoigt it reads very close to a request for specific legal advice - which are very often downvoted.

germany
Assuming the employee is not singled out due to any protected characteristic (age, sex, religion, disability etc) or otherwise inappropriate reasons (male boss wants to flirt with young female), the employer (through the manager) can determine the floor layout.
However, you said the office is three by three meters? That is below the legal minimum. An office at a minimum has to be 8m² with an additional 6m² for each additional employee. So if your managers office is 9m² that is okay for them, but it is not okay to have another employee permanently in that office. The way to the door has to be 0.9 meters wide, to the window 0.6 meters, and to the radiator 0.6 meters.  I doubt there is enough room to meet the requirements if you squeeze two people and desks into 9m² either. Atop that, the ceiling is to be 2.5 meters high.
So to summarize, for normal reasons (and "I like it better" is a good enough reason) that do not discriminate against protected characteristics, a manager can decide what the floor plan looks like and where each employee is placed. But they cannot place two people into an office smaller than 14m².
Based on the workplace ordinance, the technical rules for workplaces:

Arbeitsstättenverordnung (ArbStättV): Technische Regel für Arbeitsstätten ASR A1.2


Are female bosses allowed to flirt with older male employees in Germany?

@littleadv there is no law prohibiting consensual flirting.

The answer specifically mentioned male boss wants to flirt with young female, so I wonder if female boss flirting with and older male is appropriate. As to no laws prohibiting consensual flirting, I believe sexual harassment laws prohibit it even if the employee doesn't explicitly complain (because of the power dynamics).

@littleadv Unfortunately, we are still knee deep in structural sexism. Since harassment is all about power, a young female can theoretically harass an older male, but it is so rare that it makes for a very bad example. I wish we lived in a better society, where the opportunity to be a bad person was more equally divided between the genders. But in theory, it is about harassment, all else being equal, not who is male, female or the boss.
